# Притяжательные прилагательные

Tags: орфография, прилагательные

Как правильно говорить: Лерин или Лерын? Ленин или Ленын?

Comment: А почему "-ын"-то? Неужели человек с родным русским может там приознести твердое Н?!

Answer (score -1):

ЛерИн (Чей?), ленин(Чей?). Не путать с фамилией вождя.